# Bluetooth ID not same as scanned by other devices

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-ble-plx, react-native-ble-manager

I am working on an app that scans for nearby Bluetooth devices then checks the database if the user is present with Bluetooth ID If it's present display it to the other user nearby.

but the issue is when the person installs the app we get the Bluetooth ID and store it in a database but after that while scanning the Bluetooth ID changes.

Bluetooth id in the local device is not the same as the scanned ( by another device)

is there any way we can do this other than Bluetooth ID or how can we get a unique ID - I am Using react-native-ble-manager

Answer (score 0):

Since many people/developers have used the BD_ADDR to identify and track mobile devices and their owners, mobile operating systems today use dynamically assigned BD_ADDRs that change frequently. This is done to protect the privacy of mobile device users.

If you want to track mobile devices, you could write an application that transmits a unique ID that allows you to track those devices ...

Comment: So cant we scan for nearby Bluetooth devices and do the above task?